# Conflict between Stanford Parser & Stanford POS tagger

Tags: maven, nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am working on a project which requires me to add *POS* tags to an input string. I am also going to use *grammatical dependency structure* generated by the Stanford parser for later processing.

Something to point out before I jump to my problem.

1. For **POS tagging** I am using http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml (Version 3.3.1)
2. For **grammetical dependency** generation I am using http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download (version 3.3.1)

I included both these jars in my class path.(*By include I am using maven to pull stanford parser jar from maven repository and including POStagger jar using steps mentioned later*)

Now the problem is whenever I try to get the POS tags for an input string I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.getTaggerDataInputStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/DataInputStream;
```

My intuition says that this is because Stanford parser jar also has Maxent package that contains TaggerConfig class. Every time I ask for POS tags for a string the program looks into the Stanford parser jar instead of Stanford POStagger jar hence the error.

I am using maven and couldn't find the POStagger jar on Maven central so I included it into my local maven repository using instructions on http://charlie.cu.cc/2012/06/how-add-external-libraries-maven/ link.

I would really appreciate if anyone can point out any solution to this problem

Comment: try to post this SO link and problem also on their mailing list, http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Mail

Answer (score 0):

You are using two jar files. Go to the BuildPath and reverse the order of your imported jars. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The method Java is complaining about was in releases of the Stanford POS Tagger in the 2009-2011 period, but is not in any recent (or ancient) release.

So what this means is that you have another jar on your class path which contains an old version of the Stanford POS tagger hidden inside it, and its `MaxentTagger` has been invoked, not the one from the v3.3.1 jars (due to class path search order). You should find it and complain.

The most common case recently has been the CMU ark-tweet-nlp.jar.  See: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml#nosuchmethoderror.

The overlapping classes of the Stanford releases are not a problem: Providing you use the same version of the tagger and parser, they are identical.